# if I were to work on an arbitrary real vector space $E, (dim E = n)$, would proving theorems on $\mathbb{R}^n$ make them valid in $E$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, group-isomorphism, vector-space-isomorphism

> Mathematically speaking, if I were to work on an arbitrary real vector
>   space $E, (dim E = n)$, would proving theorems on $\mathbb{R}^n$ make
>   them valid in $E$ ?

We know that if we fix our field, in this case $\mathbb{R}$, any two $\mathbb{R}$-space, vector space, of dimension $n$ would be isomorphic to each other, so if I were to prove some theorem valid on an arbitrary vector space $E$ defined on the field $\mathbb{R}$, can I just treat $E$ as $\mathbb{R}^n$ and make the proof and say that this is proof also valid on $E$ ?

If so, while doing the proof on $\mathbb{R}^n$, If I treat $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a model for $n$ dimensional geometry, would this make any difference for the case above ?

Comment: None, as long as you have assertion about the vector structure.

Comment: @Bernard Can you check what you have written because I couldn't understand what you mean at all. Plus, saying something without giving any reason is meaningless.

Comment: I just meant that $E$ has the same properties as $\mathbf R^n$ *as long as* these are vector space properties. Not other properties. I don't think this requires any proof. This is just a commonsense observation.

Comment: @Bernard Ok, thank you for explanation, but can't I just consider $E$ as a n-dimensioanal geometry ?

Comment: @Bernard I guess even if I do that, I need make sure the isomorphism preserve the _geometric_ properties also ?

Comment: This depends on what you mean by geometric properties, but since the end of the 19th century, geometry *is* linear algebra (with its own vocabulary sometimes)..

Comment: @Bernard What I meant by geometric properpties is, for example in the case $n=3$, physical geometry that we are perceiving, i.e Euclidian geometry model.

Comment: The equivalence of statements about vectors of $E$ and vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ will be preserved if you work with coordinates or other similar "objects" as dimension. Think that you could have properties in the vector space of polynomials and these properties could not exist in other isomorphic spaces, as the divisibility between polynomials.

Comment: Euclidean geometry model supposes a further structure: an inner product, which gives rise to a metric on the space. Without an inner product, you cannot define orthogonality, for instance. All you can infer from $\mathbf R^n$ is pure vector space properties. But of course  you can have inner product spaces isomorphisms.

Comment: @Bernard Ok, I got it. Thanks a lot guys.